# Laravel 4 Routing (controller not found)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Help please, i am using Laravel4 but for some reason i can not get it to work on my mac at home,i have no problems with the mac at work, either i am missing something obvious or my mac is set up different.

the problem i am having is that i can only get the HomeController To Work if i try to use the Test Controller i get Controller method not found.  the whooops error gives Controller Method Not Found

```
REDIRECT_URL    /test
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL     HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    
REQUEST_URI     /test
SCRIPT_NAME     /index.php
PATH_INFO   /test
PATH_TRANSLATED     redirect
```

my routes

```
Route::controller('test', 'TestController');
```

and my Test Controller

```
class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
       return View::make('test.index');
    }

}
```

my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

rewrites are enabled

am i missing the obvious?

thanks for any help

Comment: do you see the routes when you type `php artisan routes`?

Comment: thanks for the reply this is what i am getting | GET /test/index/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}  |      | TestController@getIndex       |                |               |
|        | GET /test                                 |      | TestController@getIndex       |                |               |
|        | GET /test/{_missing}                      |      | TestController@missingMethod  |

Comment: I had a similar situation with my local development environment. You may need to update Apache httpd.conf file. I will write an answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar situation in my local development environment. The Laravel 4 app that was deployed on my remote server was working perfectly, however I couldn't get it to work on my local machine. The problem was that only the root folder of the app (/public - Home Controller) was accessible and none of my routes were working.

The problem was in the configuration of Apache which was not allowing loading of `.htaccess` files. My solution was to define a new Directory statement for my sites path as follows:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You may insert this in `httpd.conf` or in any configuration file that is being loaded. If there is already a definition for that path, you should update it accordingly. In my case I added the code above to my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file along with the virtual host definition:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin your@email.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/sites/laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
    ServerAlias www.laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally add this line to your `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1   laravel.dev
```

In this way, you can reach your local environment via this URI: http://laravel.dev

Comment: Got it work with your help but needed a few changes i was getting a 500 error <VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "/Users/me/Sites/mysite/public"
<Directory "/Users/me/route/mysite//public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
    ServerName mysite.dev
</VirtualHost> thank you very much i have tried to comment up but i says i dont have enough reputtation i need a score of 15 i am very greatfull though

Comment: Sure thing. I am glad that it is solved. If you think my answer answers your question please select it as the correct answer. You will gain points, too.

Comment: Thanks for that i have a reputation of 17 now so voted the answer up 1 thank you very much